# Working with multiple code files and folders in Python

Tags: python, import

I am new to Python and I haven't figured out a simple way of separating code in multiple code files and folders.

What I do today is: for each folder I create an `__init__.py` file. Sometimes it's empty. I don't know why I do it, but it seems necessary. That's the first difference from working with C#.

The second difference is that for any file to reference any another I must use an import, like `from model.table import Table`. And if I have multiple references I need to use multiple imports:

```
from model import table1,table2
```

and then in the rest of the code I must use `table1.Table1` per example. If I don't want to, I should

```
from model.table1 import Table1
from model.table2 import Table2
```

and then I can use simply `Table1`

That differs too much from what I'm used to in C#, where if all files were in the same namespace, we didn't have to `import`. Is there a simpler way for me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should read up on modules: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Basically, I think you aren't organizing your code right. With Python, directories and files have a meaning; it's not just what you write into the files. With every new directory (with `__init__.py`) and every new file you create a new "namespace"...

If you have the file `/mydatabase/model.py`
and the `Table1`, `Table2`, etc defined in that `model.py` file you can simply:

```
from mydatabase.model import *
```

Do not create a new file for each `Table` class!

Answer (score 1):

The python import system is fairly similar to C#'s namespaces from what I understand of it. You can customize import behavior of modules in `__init__.py` if you really want to. You can also use `import *` or `from x import *` to pull all public objects defined by a module into your current namespace.

Consider in C#:

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("hello world!");
```

In python, you could do (using this completely contrived situation):

```
system/
system/__init__.py
system/console.py
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
import console
```

In `system/console.py`:

```
import sys

def write_line(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
```

Now in your python code you could do:

```
from system import *
console.write_line('hello world!')
```

This is not generally considered a good idea in Python, however. For a bit more detail and good recommendations, check out this article: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm